# DLookup returning error 3075 and 2471

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm currently working with MS Access 2007 and I'm trying to access a certain field called "Quantity" at the "Products" table.

So far I've used:

```
Dim test As Variant
test = DLookup("[Id]", "Products", "[Product]=" & ProductCmboBox.value)
```

Which returned the following error msg (3075): "Syntax error (missing operator) in the query expression '[Product]='".

I've also tried without the "[" and "]" things, which returned the same error;

I've tried also

```
Dim test As Variant
test = DLookup("Id", "Produtos", "Produto= '" & ProductCmboBox.value & "'")
```

Which gave the following error msg (2471):
"The expression you inserted as query parameter generated this error: 'Id'"

What am I doing wrong?
Btw, the error msgs where in portuguese, so the translation is not accurate, sry

Comment: Is the Product field a text type? If so, your English version needs apostrophe delimiters and make sure the combobox is bound to the correct column if it is multi-column. Are the object names really assigned English version?

Comment: I just translated the object names. As for the field, it is a text type and i tried with and without the apostrophe, as i showed.
When i print the cmbBox.value, it shows the index, which is the value I 'm expecting

Comment: *"I'm trying to access a certain field called "Quantity"*... What you are trying to return is `[Id]` not `[Quantity]`. Are you sure you have a field called `Id` in your `Products` table?

Comment: Oh, oops, I should have seen that also. If you use a multi-column combobox that has multiple fields from the Products table, DLookup would not be needed. Just reference the combobox column that has data you need. Combobox index begins with 0: `test = ProductCmboBox.Column(x)`

Comment: Oh man, that's embarrassing, you're right. I was using the wrong fields to debug but forgot to change it

Comment: Also begs question as to why you have Quantity field in Products table. Sounds like you are saving aggregate data instead of calculating when needed. Are you continually updating the Quantity field as product is received and used instead of calculating net balance of transactions?

Comment: The quantity field will be updated. I don't have all the tables ready yet, so i'm using that field. At one point, i'll change it